2003 Chevy Malibu Igntion cylinder fell out
I have a 2003 Chevy Malibu and the igntion cylinder fell out when I was starting it. I was able to get it back in, but if I accidentally pull on the key when the starter is engaged (turning the key past the "on" position) it will fall out super easily. I ordered a new ignition cylinder on Amazon knowing that I would have a different key for the ignition and doors but I noticed the small pin that was causing the problems. 
I tried to pull the new pin out to transfer it but I can't seem to get it out. Is there a way to do this? Could I get a replacement part so I don't have to replace the whole cylinder?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Disclaimer: I have no experience with GM ignition locks. This is an educated guess from repairing other locks and from the picture you posted.
I would expect that after removing the cap, the lock's core can be pulled out and that this will get you access to the pin you want to remove.
It should be possible to pry off the cap after undoing two small dents. Do not remove the core from the housing yet when removing the cap! Insert the key to secure the tumblers in the core before carefully pulling out the core.
The lock can contain small springs and other small parts which you do not want to loose!
I think you will have two options to go from there:

Extract the pin from the new lock and install it into the old lock as you planned.
Transfer the old lock's core to the new lock.

As a last resort, if neither core nor pin are interchangeable between the locks, you may succeed transferring the old lock's tumblers to the new core. You will have to keep the tumblers' exact position and orientation.
This parts catalog illustration is for door locks, which are slightly different, but it gives you an idea of what to expect inside the lock.

This worked! This is the video I ended up following. I bought a new ignition cylinder, transferred the tumblers over, and now I have no anti theft warning and can use my old keys again. For anyone trying this, be VERY careful when you pull the tumblers out. They're so small and one small breeze can send them flying.
